# How to increase Jelly Bean AVD emulator speed

Tags: android-emulator

I have installed the latest ADT for Windows 64-bit platform. My laptop configuration is:

- 2.2 GHz dual core processor
- 3 GB ram
- 300 GB HDD

The AVD boots slow. How can I increase its speed? What other ways can I optimize the emulator to work more quickly?

Answer (score 1):

When you first run an AVD, make sure that saving snapshots is enabled. Get it to a state you like (probably the Home screen), and kill the emulator, letting it save the snapshot. Then edit the AVD to NOT save snapshots, but do boot from snapshot. Your AVD will now launch and close quickly, comparatively speaking.

Answer (score 0):

One thing has worked well for me. Reduce the screen resolution of your AVD to the lowest necessary values.